# Jackson LIb JsonArray format

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using jackson lib to add json object into jsonarray then Stringify my jsonarray to save it into my a table as string

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.put("id",1).put("data","test");

JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
arr.add(obj);

arr.toString();

//out : [{"map":{"id":1,"data":"test"},"empty":false}]

//result wanted : [{"id":1,"data":"test"}]
```

So how can I get the last result without map and empty keys, and why it adds those keys in the first place ?

Comment: which jackson version are you using?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ 2.8.4

Comment: You are not using Jackson, You are using org.json

Comment: @Sharon no, org.json uses `JSONObject` (capital JSON)

Comment: well, Jackson uses JsonNode, and ObjectNode but not JsonObject

Comment: I'm using vertx which use JacksonLib https://github.com/Crunc/jackson-datatype-vertx

Answer (score 0):

I made small changes to the code, i used the following maven dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810   and you are using org.json but not jackson.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("id",1).put("data","test");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        arr.put(obj);

        System.out.println(arr.toString());
```

output: [{"data":"test","id":1}]

Comment: You're using org.json... The question is not

Comment: As @cricket_007 said i'm using jackson lib and not org.json

Comment: @azelix You're really using VertX as a wrapper around Jackson. http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally I get it.  So, the documentation for the jackson module clearly shows how serialization of a `JsonObject` should be done. It is **not** using `toString()`:

> Serialization (JsonElement -> String)
>
> ```
> ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
> om.registerModule(new VertxJsonModule());
>
> String jsonObject = mapper.writeValueAsString(new JsonObject());
>
> String jsonArray = mapper.writeValueAsString(new JsonArray());
> ```